# How do I know that I am connected to a config server

Tags: mongodb

I need a simple check for identifying that I am connected to a MongoDB config server.

I can check the process to differentiate between mongod and mongos:

```
> db.serverStatus().process;
mongod
```

Now I make an assumption that config server is the one without a replica set name, but it would not always hold true. I check that below returns a NULL value.

```
> db.serverStatus().repl.setName;
```

What is a better way to identify config server from mongod in a simple manner? This would be useful for custom prompt function based on the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found one way to do it.

On config server:

```
> db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.sharding.clusterRole
configsvr
```

On shard server:

```
> db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.sharding.clusterRole
shardsvr
```

Have to be careful as `db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.sharding.clusterRole` is not always defined.